# override functions / extend during runtime?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have 3 scripts like this:

A.gd:

```
extends Node

func something():
    print("A something")
```

B.gd:

```
extends "res://A.gd"

func something():
    print("B something")

func something_else():
    print("B something_else")
```

C.gd:

```
extends "res://A.gd"

func something():
    print("C something")
```

is there a way I can extend B in C during runtime so that I can override `something()` with C but I don't loose the functionality of `something_else()` from B?

like the runtime equivalent of:

C.gd:

```
extends "res://B.gd"

func something():
    print("C something")
```

#### Why am I doing this?

I have multiple `B_1.gd`, `B_2.gd`, etc
so if I want to extend anyone of them with `C.gd`
I have to make multiple files `C_1.gd`, `C_2.gd` etc for every individual one
which becomes annoying when I'm using the same `C.gd` for every `B_<number>.gd` file

so is something like this possible (maybe in c#)? or is there any workaround?

**Note:**
Both `C.gd` and `B_<number>.gd` always inherit from `A.gd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an script at runtime.

A minimal example is like this:

```
var script = GDScript.new()
script.source_code = "func run():print('hello world')"
script.reload()
```

If you define static methods there, you can use them right away. You can also instance the script. Or set the script of an existing `Object` to it.

---

Thus, you can use your existing code as template. First read the source code from the original script file:

```
var file := File.new()
file.open("res://C.gd", File.READ)
var source_code := file.get_as_text()
file.close()
```

**Addendum**: As alternative, you could use a `String` literal.

Then replace the path with the one you want in the source code:

```
source_code = source_code.replace("res://A.gd", "res://B_1.gd")
```

**Addendum**: As alternative, you could have a `String` prepared for `String.format`.

Then create an `GDScript` with that modified source code:

```
var script := GDScript.new()
script.source_code = source_code
script.reload()
```

**Addendum**: `reload` returns an `Error` (`int`), which would be non zero (`OK`) if there is something wrong with the code.

Then use that script however you want. For example instance it:

```
var instance := script.new()
```

Or set it to an existing instance:

```
instance.set_script(script)
```

Comment: is this performance consuming if I use it multiple times within a short period of time?

Comment: @arsher Once created, they are like any other script, use them all you want. I don't know how the performance scales, but at least I can tell you that it would be related to how complex the code is, because reloading the code runs the parser.

Comment: @arsher I should clarify, I refer to the performance of creating the scripts, not using them. The performance of using them is like any other script.