# How to directly Inherit from newly created GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm creating a [script during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74665882/15182215) and I'd like another script to extend it
so far I've tried this:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var script_A=GDScript.new()
    script_A.source_code="extends Node2D"
    script_A.reload()
    
    var script_B=GDScript.new()
    script_B.source_code='extends "'+script_A.resource_path+'"'
    script_B.reload()
    
    var new_node=Node2D.new()
    new_node.set_script(script_A)
    add_child(new_node)
```

but it doesn't seem to work since `script_A.resource_path` returns an empty string
So is there any way to get where the script_A is stored in the memory so we can extend it from that path?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to extend a script from an in memory script is to first write the base script to storage.

```
var script_A=GDScript.new()
script_A.source_code="extends Node2D"
script_A.resource_path = "user://script_A.gd"
script_A.reload()

ResourceSaver.save(script_A)

var script_B=GDScript.new()
script_B.source_code='extends "'+script_A.resource_path+'"'
script_B.reload()
```

Note that we write it to `user://` because `res://` is not always write-able.

Comment: This did occur to me but what happens when I create a new script and replace the current one which is saved via `ResourceSaver`? Does creating a new script pile up in the storage every time?